# Retrofit2 get data GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 41 path $.data"

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I am new start with Retrofit when i am trying to get data form api use Retrofit2 + Rxjava:

**ApiService:**

```html
@GET("news/get_comments/{newsid}/{count}/{offset}")
Observable<ResultResponse<CommentList>> getComment(@Header("api_key") String key, @Path("newsid") String newsid, @Path("count")String count, @Path("offset")String offset);
```

```js
public void getComment(String item_id, int pageNow) {
        int offset = (pageNow - 1) * 10;
        Log.i("commentlist", offset+"");
        Log.i("commentlist",pageNow+"");
        addSubscription(AppClient.getApiService().getComment(ApiService.KEY,item_id,"10",offset+""), new SubscriberCallBack<CommentList>() {
            @Override
            protected void onSuccess(CommentList response) {
                Logger.i("commentist",response.toString());
                mvpView.onGetCommentSuccess(response);
            }

        });
    }
```

GSON throwing an error:`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 41 path $.data`

Comment: Add the json you're getting back. also, add the ResultResponse and CommentList objects you created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because your response starts with [] not {} actually you are getting a jsonarray instead of jsonobject

Comment: yes bro your are right thx